# What is cin doing inside argument of if?

Tags: c++, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would std::ostringstream convert to bool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835590/how-would-stdostringstream-convert-to-bool)

```
#include<iostream.h>
 void main() {
   if(cin>>2) {    // what is cin>>2 doing inside arg of if
      cout<<"if works";
   } else {
       cout<<"else works";
     }
 }
```

**We don't get error in this code.But Always`if` statement works** *why? how?*

Comment: It is evaluated like any other expression, apparently to a non-zero value.

Comment: and `void main()` is deprecated, it should be `int main()`. And you either need a `using std::cout; using std::cin;` or `using namespace std;` before the first use of `cin` or `cout`.

Comment: I have compiled this using turbo-c++

Comment: This does not compile for me. And there are so many other warnings (like the use of iostream.h) which indicate you are probably using an ancient compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cin >> 2` is invalid. `cin >> integervar` is valid, assuming that's what you mean?

The standard library class `ios` which `basic_istream` (and thus `cin`) inherits from overloads `operator void *` (and `operator!`) to allow you to do such tests.

`operator void *` returns 0 if `failbit` or `badbit` is set - aka the last extraction failed.

This is the "standard" way of combining extraction and checking if the extraction succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(cin>>2)
```

This wouldn't even compile.  See this :  http://ideone.com/MiEkq

What you probably mean is :  `if(cin>>var)`

If that is so, then it means IF the read from the input stream succeeds, then then `if` block will be executed because after successful read, the returned `std::istream &` can implicitly convert into `true`, otherwise it converts into `false`.

BTW, the return type of  `main()` should be `int`.

Comment: @ Nawaz it compiles using turbo-c++

Comment: @Suhail Gupta: Then you should get a better compiler - if you *actually* use `cin >> 2` the compiler's broken.

Comment: @ Erik what do you mean by `compiler's broken`?

Comment: @Suhail: That means, Turbo-C++ doesn't follow the language specification. What it compiles is NOT C++. ... Just click this link and see the error : http://ideone.com/MiEkq

Comment: @Suhail Gupta::`What is wrong with using turbo C?`-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920351/what-is-wrong-with-using-turbo-c