# Cin object return value c++

Tags: c++, cin

I woud like to ask what is return value of cin? I know it is istream object and when it is used in expression like `if(!cin)` there is actually called some function and I woud like to know what function it actually is. cin.fail() or cin.good() or..
Is `if(!cin) same as if(cin.fail())?`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5695146/what-is-cin-doing-inside-argument-of-if

Answer (score 1):

### Yes.

`cin` overloads casting operators, and they return flag status `fail()`.

A possible implementation:

```
operator void*() const {
    return !fail();
}

explicit operator bool(){
   return !fail();
}

bool operator!() const {
   return fail();
}
```

Look at [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).