# Why doesn't this comparison to bool work for an istream?

Tags: c++, boolean, istream

I have a flimsy understanding of how/why istream can be used in conditionals. I have read this question:([Why istream object can be used as a bool expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8117566/252428)).

I don't understand why this compiles without error…

```
while (cin >> n) {
    // things and stuff
}
```

…while this fails to compile (message `error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and '__istream_type' (aka 'basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >'))`)

```
while (true == (cin >> n)) {
    // things and stuff
}
```

Comment: Which compiler is this?

Comment: libc++, I think. (Xcode and/or CodeRunner)

Comment: Well, my main concern was the fact that it says `int` instead of `bool`. In any case, there's supposed to be an explicit conversion operator to `bool`, but I don't think any implementations have it yet.

Comment: in c++11 mode or not? `operator bool` was only added in c++11.

Comment: yes, c++11 mode. (I was confused about `int` as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the implicit conversion operator of `cin` is

```
operator void*() const { ... }
```

and it can evaluate to zero, so you can check it against zero

```
while (cin >> x) {}
```

Conversion operator for `bool` declared as `explicit` so your expression will not invoke it:

```
explicit operator bool(){ ... }
```

So, you need an explicit cast:

```
if (true == static_cast<bool>(cin >> a))
{
}
```

Comment: There's also an `operator bool()`.

Comment: @0x499602D2, Also might be a bit much. It was *changed* to `explicit operator bool()` in C++11.

Comment: Interesting. I thought that I might have to cast but didn't understand why. Thank you. (can't accept answer yet.)

Comment: You say that 'it's just useful for testing against `0`' But that expression evaluates to true when cin reads a 0 as well. Does that (the 0 that you mentioned) mean that `cin` returned `NULL|nullptr` from the implicit cast?

Comment: I edited that part a little. For more info read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19385215/952747). That operator returns `!fail()`.

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> n` returns an `istream&`. Because the result is used in a comparison, the compiler searches for an `operator==(bool, istream)`, which it cannot find. Therefore, you get an error message.