# Function prototype difficulties

Tags: c++, function, function-prototypes

I am having difficulties in getting my program working properly. For the part of the project I am having difficulties with, I need to create a function that validates two different numbers input by the user. However in the whenever I run the program I get two errors going on.

One is that the input is first read as me inputting 0 (even though I didn't)

And the second is that it treats it runs the first input through the second inputs validation test

Function prototypes:

```
int validate(int , int);
```

Main:

```
do
{       
    //display the menu
    displayMenu();
    cin >> choice; 
    validate(choice, months);

    // process the user's choice
    if (choice != QUIT_CHOICE)
    {
        // get the number of months
        cout << over3 << "For how many months? ";
        cin >> months; 
        validate(choice, months);
}
```

And the function prototype in question:

```
int validate(int choice, int months)
{
while (choice < 1 || choice > 4)
{
    cout << over3 << choice << " is not between 1 and 4! Try again: ";  
    cin >> choice;
}

while (months < 1 || months > 12)
{
    cout << over3 << months << " is not between 1 and 12! Try again: "; 
    cin >> months;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both of them are independent of each other, you need to separate the into two functions for your purpose : `validateChoice` which consists of the first while loop and `validateMonths` which consists of second while loop.

If you want single function itself you need to pass appropriate parameter

```
int validate(int value, int lowLimit, int HighLimit)
{
    while(value < lowLimit || value > HighLimit)
    {
        //print error message here
        cin>> value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

In main, do

```
cin >> choice;
choice = validate(choice, 1, 4);
```

Similarly for `months`.

Comment: The correct way to use a `std` stream for reading is `if(cin >> value) { /* do something with value */ } else { /* failure to read */ }`. You still perform a formatting read without checking it if succeeded.

Comment: okay thats what i think I 'm going to have to do.. my professor says to use a function named validate to validate both of those values but I really have no idea how to do that

Comment: @user3470987 Isn't my answer showing you same thing ? Function called `validate` which validates both values. You just need to pass different arguments during different function calls.

Comment: oh okay okay i gotcha, that kinda makes sense kinda. do you know what pmr means?

Comment: He is asking you to check if the read is successful. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5695176/2829267)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown how (if at all) you initialize `choice` and `months` before your `do` loop, but my guess is you haven't. Therefore here:

```
cin >> choice; 
validate(choice, months);
```

You are passing an uninitialized value as the second argument to `validate`. An uninitialized value could be anything; in your case, it seems to be zero.